# Converting between std::wstring and std::string

Tags: c++, strings, converting

While researching ways to convert back and forth between `std::wstring` and `std::string`, I found [this conversation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvc/thread/0f749fd8-8a43-4580-b54b-fbf964d68375) on the MSDN forums.

There were two functions that, to me, looked good. Specifically, these:

```
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

std::string ws2s(const std::wstring& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
    char* buf = new char[len];
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len, 0, 0); 
    std::string r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}
```

However, the double allocation and the need to delete the buffer concern me (performance and exception safety) so I modified them to be like this:

```
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
    std::wstring r(len, L'\0');
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, &r[0], len);
    return r;
}

std::string ws2s(const std::wstring& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
    std::string r(len, '\0');
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, &r[0], len, 0, 0); 
    return r;
}
```

Unit testing indicates that this works in a nice, controlled environment but will this be OK in the vicious and unpredictable world that is my client's computer?

Answer (score 13):

I would, and have, redesign your set of functions to resemble casts:

```
std::wstring x;
std::string y = string_cast<std::string>(x);
```

This can have a lot of benefits later when you start having to deal with some 3rd party library's idea of what strings should look like.

Comment: I love the syntax. Can you share the code?

Comment: Oooh. That looks nice. How would one do that? Just make a template with specializations to convert between the various string types?

Comment: @Billy someone posted a codereview question for string_cast implementation [on here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/c-string-cast-template-function/1466#1466) if you guys are interested.

Comment: Why, though? I think I prefer to have functions `to_string` and `to_wstring`, similar to the standard library (in my own namespace of course).

Answer (score 12):

**Actually *my* unit testing shows that your code is wrong!**

The problem is that you include the zero terminator in the output string, which is not supposed to happen with `std::string` and friends. Here's an example why this can lead to problems, especially if you use `std::string::compare`:

```
// Allocate string with 5 characters (including the zero terminator as in your code!)
string s(5, '_');

memcpy(&s[0], "ABCD\0", 5);

// Comparing with strcmp is all fine since it only compares until the terminator
const int cmp1 = strcmp(s.c_str(), "ABCD"); // 0

// ...however the number of characters that std::string::compare compares is
// someString.size(), and since s.size() == 5, it is obviously not equal to "ABCD"!
const int cmp2 = s.compare("ABCD"); // 1

// And just to prove that string implementations automatically add a zero terminator
// if you call .c_str()
s.resize(3);
const int cmp3 = strcmp(s.c_str(), "ABC"); // 0
const char term = s.c_str()[3]; // 0

printf("cmp1=%d, cmp2=%d, cmp3=%d, terminator=%d\n", cmp1, cmp2, cmp3, (int)term);
```

Comment: I found the addition of the terminator annoying too: it also broke a string addition in my case. I ended up adding the boolean parameter `includeTerminator` to both methods.

Comment: @reallynice see: [FlagArgument (martinfowler.com)](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html)

Answer (score 12):

It really depends what codecs are being used with `std::wstring` and `std::string`.

This answer assumes that the `std::wstring` is using a UTF-16 encoding, and that the conversion to `std::string` will use a UTF-8 encoding.

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

std::wstring utf8ToUtf16(const std::string& utf8Str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> conv;
    return conv.from_bytes(utf8Str);
}

std::string utf16ToUtf8(const std::wstring& utf16Str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(utf16Str);
}
```

This answer uses the STL and does not rely on a platform specific library.

Comment: This is the best answer because is the only working. Thank you.

Comment: https://dbj.org/c17-codecvt-deprecated-panic/ ... my shameless plug might help ...

Comment: @DBJDBJ Your proposed solution is by no means a replacement to `wstring_convert` from <codecvt>. You kind of down-play the problem by saying the approach is "_somewhat controversial_" - in my opinion, it's much more than that. It's wrong. I have uses of `wstring_convert` which your solution cannot replace. It cannot convert true unicode strings like `"おはよう"`, as it's not a true conversion; it's a cast. Consider making that more explicit in your text ;)

Comment: @Marc.2377 -- well ,I think I have placed plenty of warnings in that text. I even have mentioned the "casting" word. there is even a link to "that article" ... Many thanks for reading in any case.

Comment: FFWD to 2019 -- `<codecvt>` is deprecated

Answer (score 6):

One thing that may be an issue is that it assumes the string is ANSI formatted using the currently active code page (CP_ACP). You might want to consider using a specific code page or CP_UTF8 if it's UTF-8.

Comment: This may be a silly question but, how can I tell? For my usage these will typically be filenames.

Comment: How do you obtain the filenames? That will determine the correct code page to use.

Comment: @Jere.Jones: One way is to check if the string is valid UTF-8.  If not, assume it's ANSI.

Comment: @dan04: ANSI requires that a code page is specified. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page.

Comment: Further note: The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) recommends not using CP_ACP for strings intended for permanent storage, because the active page may be changed at any time

Comment: CP_UTF8 https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/desktop/Intl/code-page-identifiers

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend changing this:

```
int len;
int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

...to this:

```
int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Slightly more concise, `len`'s scope is reduced, and you don't have an uninitialised variable floating round (ok, just for one line) as a trap for the unwary.

Answer (score 3):

I don't do any Windows development, so I can't comment on the `WideCharToMultiByte` part being safe.

The one thing I would say though is to ensure you are using the proper types for everything.  For example, `string.length()` returns a `std::string::size_type` (most likely a `size_t`, the constructor also takes a `std::string::size_type`, but that one isn't as big of a deal).  It probably won't ever bite you, but it is something to be careful of to ensure you don't have any overflows in other code you may be writing.

Comment: Well, it returns a `std::string::size_type`.

Comment: @Jon: True, but I've never it seen it not be equal to the representation of a `size_t`.  I'll modify the answer though, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Jon: `std::string::size_type` is always a `std::size_t`.

Comment: @GMan: I was just being pedantic out of boredom. SGI says it's "an unsigned integral type that can represent any nonnegative value of the container's distance type"—that is, `difference_type`—and that both of these must be `typedef` s for existing types, but this doesn't imply that `size_type` has to be equivalent to `size_t`. Is there something else at work here?

Comment: @Jon: I'm not sure why SGI matters. The *standard* says `std::string::size_type` is `allocator_type::size_type`, and the default allocator's `size_type` is `std::size_t`.

Comment: @GMan: Alright, that's what I was looking for. SGI doesn't matter, except of course when it does. But hey, `size_type` is the first one in the chain, for all it matters. Or the last, depending on where you're standing.

Answer (score 0):

When we're using `std::string` and `std::wstring`, we need `#include <string>`.

There's no declaration of `MultiByteToWideChar()` or `WideCharToMultiByte()`.  Their names suggest they might be some thin wrapper around `std::mbstowcs()` and `std::wcstombs()` respectively, but without seeing them, it's hard to be sure.

It would be much simpler and easier to understand if we used the standard functions to convert between null-terminated multibyte and wide-character strings.

Depending on the use case, a `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>` facet might be more appropriate.  Then there's very little code to be written, and in particular, no need to guess at the possible output length.

Answer (score -1):

I've only briefly looked over your code. I haven't worked with std::string much but I've worked a lot with the API.

Assuming you got all your lengths and arguments right (sometimes making sure the terminator and wide vs multibyte lengths are all right can be tricky), I think you're on the right track. I think the first routines you posted unnecessarily allocate an additional buffer. It isn't needed.

Answer (score -4):

No, this is dangerous! The characters in a std::string may not be stored in a contiguous memory block and you must not use the pointer `&r[0]` to write to any characters other than that character! This is why the `c_str()` function returns a `const` pointer.

It might work with MSVC, but it will probably break if you switch to a different compiler or STL library.

Comment: -1: Wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256160/how-bad-is-code-using-stdbasic-stringt-as-a-contiguous-buffer