# Converting from std::wstring to std::string in Linux

Tags: c++, strings, converting, linux

I was bothered by inability of C++ to mix `cout` and `wcout` in the same program - so I've found this question:

[Converting between std::wstring and std::string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/419/converting-between-stdwstring-and-stdstring)

It didn't help me because it was mostly about MS Windows (I'm on Linux), but thanks to it I've found something similar to the `WideCharToMultiByte` functions in the C++ standard library.

My goal was just to output wide strings to `cout` intermittently with regular strings. I've written two variants of conversion function, which take wide string as an argument and return a regular string, containing multi-byte characters, ready to be sent to the `cout` (provided that the locale is appropriate).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct T
{
  std::string a;
  std::wstring b;
};

std::string Convert1(const std::wstring& WS)
// ------ conversion using the wcstombs function 
{
  const unsigned wlen = WS.length();
  char buf[wlen * sizeof(std::wstring::value_type) + 1];
  const ssize_t res = std::wcstombs(buf, WS.c_str(), sizeof(buf));
  return (res >= 0) ? buf : "?";
}

std::string Convert2(const std::wstring& WS)
// ------ conversion using the wcsrtombs function 
{
  mbstate_t st = {};
  const unsigned wlen = WS.length();
  wchar_t wbuf[wlen + 1];
  const size_t copied = WS.copy(wbuf, wlen);
  wbuf[copied] = L'\0';
  const wchar_t* wptr = wbuf;
  char buf[wlen * sizeof(std::wstring::value_type) + 1];
  const ssize_t res = std::wcsrtombs(buf, &wptr, sizeof(buf), &st);
  return (res >= 0) ? buf : "?";
}

int main()
{
  T t = {"Hello", L"Привет"};
  std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
  cout << t.a << endl;
  cout << Convert2(t.b) << endl;
}
```

It works for me now... Will it work in other setups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `ssize_t` is essentially unsigned; that is, the comparison `res >= 0` is always true.

  The test should be

  ```
  res != static_cast<std::size_t>(-1)
  ```
- `<cstdlib>` and `<cwchar>` headers are missing
- You don't need to `WS.copy(wbuf, wlen)`.

  In fact, you don't need `wbuf` at all:

  ```
  const wchar_t * wptr = WS.c_str();
  std::wcsrtombs(buf, &wptr, sizeof(buf), &st);
  ```

  works just fine.
- I am not sure that calculating buffer length via `sizeof(std::wstring::value_type)` is a right way. How can you be sure that multibyte sequence will fit? I'd recommend to obtain required size by passing `NULL` to `wcsrtombs`.

PS: И тебе привет

Comment: ssize_t = "signed" size_t

Comment: Yes, copy-less variant works!